# VB.NET Sample Entity Framework 4.2 Code First Entity Splitting

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

Entity Splitting: one class, two or more tables.

Here is how it is done in C#, but I need to get it working in vb.net.
One more thing: the class name and table columns **do not** match, so I have to be able to map that out, too.

I have to get this to work this way because the place I'm working at right now is a vb.net **only** shop and the database schema is **fubar**, but they have so much (millions) of lines of code done **directly** against the database in both asp classic, vb.net, AND asp.net webforms that changing the schema right now is not realistically possible.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .Map(m =>
      {
        m.Properties(p => new { p.Title, p.Content });
        m.ToTable("Posts");
      })
    .Map(m =>
      {
        m.Properties(p => new { p.Photo });
        m.ToTable("PostPhotos");
      });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the VB equivalent of the above:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Post)().Map(Sub(m)
                                          m.Properties(Of Post)(
                                             Function(p) _
                                                New Post With {.Title= p.Title, _
                                                               .Content = p.Content })
                                          m.ToTable("Posts")
                                        End Sub).Map(Sub(m)
                                                       m.Properties(
                                                          Function(p) _
                                                            New Customer With {.Photo = p.Photo})
                                                       m.ToTable("PostPhotos")
                                                     End Sub)
```

Comment: Do you really have to have 2 Class for the DB tables? I mean Post and Photo. Is it impossible to do it with anonymous classes?

Answer (score 0):

Here a correct version (with Anonymous Type usage) of the accepted answer. I hope it will help...

You can indeed do it via dot notation, but the code indentation is really weird. I've preferred the other way : create a **EntityTypeConfiguration** Class

```
 Public Class PostConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of Post)

    Public Sub New()

        Map(Sub(m)
                m.Properties(
                   Function(p) _
                      New With {Key p.Title, Key p.Content})
                m.ToTable("Posts")
            End Sub)

        Map(Sub(m)
                m.Properties(
                   Function(p) _
                     New With {Key p.Photo })
                m.ToTable("PostPhotos")
            End Sub)

    End Sub
  End Class
```

You just have to add this config to the model, like this :

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(New PostConfiguration)
    End Sub
```